# Use variables in the name of the variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$my_array1= array("A", "B");
$my_array2= array("1", "2");
```

Is it possible to use variables **($x)** in the index of the array like this:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
Echo $my_array.$x[0];
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: `echo ${"my_array" . $x}[0];`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want variable variables https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @rjdown That's the title of the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. You don't want to use the variable in the index, you want to use it in the name of the variable.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar. The right unswer is: echo ${"my_array" . $x}[0];

Comment: But it's generally a bad idea to code like this. Use a 2-dimensional array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After referred in comment , i think it's work : [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#97222)

```html
$my_array1= array("A", "B");
$my_array2= array("1", "2");
```

and re-use your loop like:

```html
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    // to init the new name of array
    $init = 'my_array'.$x;
    // to use variable in the name of variable 
    Echo $$init[0];
    }
```

I hope it's help you

Comment: You can do it, it's just not considered good style, and your method is preferable.

Comment: yes, thanks I update my comment

Comment: Thank you rapaelec. Your solution works also for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is to be able to use key / value pairs.

You can do something like:

```
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    2  => "b",
    3  => "c",
    4 => "d",
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
}
```

Or loop througout the numeric key values as you like.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question at all. He wants to choose between `$my_array1` and `$my_array2` depending on the value of `$x`.

Comment: My apologies, you're right ! Maybe I need an extra cup of coffee today...